# How to dump PHP backtrace on live running script in lldb?

Tags: debugging, gdb, callstack, lldb, php

I'm trying to print PHP backtrace of the live running script using the following 2 simple steps:

1. Run PHP script as:

   ```
   php -r "sleep(1000);"
   ```
2. On another console, I've called directly [`zif_debug_backtrace()`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_builtin_functions.c#L2654) from `lldb`:

   ```
   echo 'call (void)zif_debug_backtrace()' | lldb -p $(pgrep -fn php)
   ```

Above worked, however the process stopped with the following warning:

```
Warning: sleep() expects at most 2 parameters, 1606408648 given in Command line code on line 1
Call Stack:
    0.0016     235152   1. {main}() Command line code:0
    0.0021     235248   2. sleep(1000) Command line code:1
```

Why the script stopped and how to prevent that? Is it possible to print PHP backtrace during live run without affecting the script?

Is it because I should specify some return address? If so, which one?

Btw. The same happening when calling `zif_debug_print_backtrace()` and when calling `custom_backtrace()` it is showing: `Backtrace null function called`. I'm using `xdebug` if that change anything.

Maybe I need to call a different function like `zend_fetch_debug_backtrace` (see: `image dump symtab`)? Or use the right arguments, if so, which one?

I'm interested either in `lldb` or `gdb` solutions.